# How to efficiently export large matlab figure to SVG editor Inkscape

Tags: matlab-figure, inkscape

I have generated a matlab figure (around 80 megabytes). This figure needs some manual editing in SVG editor. However, when i export the matlab figure to INkscape it turns to 502 Mb file (.svg) and most importantly can't be open in INkscape. In Inkscape the file shows error and error messages are not shown except for blank windows.

The code i used to export is simply `plot2svg;`

How can I solve this matlab figure exporting problem to SVG editor? Any ideas will be higly appreciated. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following two options:

1. Use the following File [Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) Export of Figures](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401-scalable-vector-graphics--svg--export-of-figures) from Matlab File exchange
2. Save as PDF or png --> Import into Inkscape and increase the resolution--> Do your modifications
3. In matlab, use [Matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) to generate a `*.tikz` file --> Compile with `Lualatex` -->Do step 1

Hope this can help